# Link DLL and class method explicitly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'd like make a dynamic library by creating a DLL and import it into my main program.
But I can't run my program correctly since I switch from LIB to DLL.

This is my DLL .h file :

```
class Connector
{
public:
    Connector(std::string _apiKey, 
              std::string _masterCode,
              std::string _masterSystem, 
              std::string _masterVersion, 
              int INTERNAL_PARAMETER = -1);
    virtual ~Connector();
    std::string query(std::string method, 
                      std::map<std::string, 
                      std::string> params);
    [...]
}
```

And this is the link code in my mainApp :

```
typedef std::string (CALLBACK* kcDLLFUNC_QUERY)(
         std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>, std::string);

HINSTANCE kcDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("Connect"));
kcDLLFUNC_QUERY kcDLLFUNC_query = (kcDLLFUNC_QUERY)GetProcAddress(kcDLL, "query");

std::map<std::string, std::string> params;
params["amount"] = "50";
std::string RES = kcDLLFUNC_query("de", params, "");
std::cout << RES << std::endl;
FreeLibrary(kcDLL);
```

Have I forgotten anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `GetProcAddress()` only works with `extern "C"` functions. The function you want to call is a member of a class, and you haven't exported either the function or the entire class.

I typically implement this by adding a define to the DLL project, and then create a header in the DLL project that defines a macro that indicates if the function/class is exported or imported. Something like this:

```
// Assumes IS_DLL is defined somewhere in the project for your DLL
// (such as in the project's Properties: C/C++ -> Preprocessor)
#ifdef IS_DLL
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And then modify your class like this:

```
#include "DllExport.h" // name of the header file defined above

class DLL_API Connector
{
public:
    Connector(std::string _apiKey, std::string _masterCode, std::string _masterSystem, std::string _masterVersion, int INTERNAL_PARAMETER = -1);
    virtual ~Connector();
    std::string query(std::string method, std::map<std::string, std::string> params);
    [...]
}
```

In your .exe, include the header for your class, and use it as usual. You also need to link to the DLL. In recent versions of Visual Studio, this is done as follows:

1. In the Solution Explorer, expand the project for the .exe.
2. Right click `References`, and select `Add Reference...`.
3. In the dialog, select `Solution` in the list on the left.
4. Select the checkbox next to the DLL's project, and press OK.

If you end up creating multiple DLLs for your program, you'll need to change the name of the defines so they don't clash (I typically include the name of the DLL in the name of each define).

Comment: How I'm supposed to switch the definition of DLL_API ? And when I try it I get some Unresolved tokens

Comment: `DLL_API` works because it will be defined for all files in the DLL's project, and won't be defined for files in the EXE's project. One step I forgot to mention is that the EXE project must link to the DLL's project. I'll update my answer with how to add a reference.

Comment: I tried and that works well ! But I need .lib file to do that. There is a way to do that without .lib file link ?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to add an `extern "C"` function that takes all the parameters you need, and then internall create an instance of your class and call the method you want. What's wrong with also generating a .lib file?

Comment: I'm creating something for our clients and they told us, that they can't use a .lib in their project.

Comment: Then your only option is to export a function that will internally use the class's method, and you pass whatever is needed to it.